# EF6: Getting Timout on Update while in For Next Loop

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table that has data which needs to be sent to a service via an API. I have created a Windows Service which starts a timer. Once the timer has elapsed it runs the SUB `ProcessRequests()`. Here I use EF to get any rows of fresh request. I then have a For Next loop which composes a json string from the various file in a row and fires an api call. All this works up to this point.

I also get a response back from the api and I need to update the corresponding row with this data as well as update the status field and the raisedOn field. Unfortunately the `dc.SaveChanges` eventually causes an exception and the exception message is a timeout or connection issue. The initial call to get fresh rows had no issues with connectivity and did not time out. I'm thinking that I may have a rowlock issue or something. Any help appreciated.

My code is:

```vb
Sub ProcessRequests()

    ' Define the various objects we're going to use
    Dim newServiceNowEvent As ServiceNowEvent = Nothing
    Dim de As New AutoTicketDBEntities

    Try

        ' Open a connnection to the database and get any Request that are not COMPLETED

        Dim EventQuery = (From r In de.Ticket_Requests
                          Order By r.Requested
                          Where r.snEventRaised <> "Completed"
                          Select r.ID, r.Prefix, r.UniqueID, r.TicketText, r.UserUniqueID, r.UserSysID, r.snEventExceptionText)

        ' Iterate through any new records
        For Each EventRequest In EventQuery

            Try

                ' Create a new instance of the OpsViewEventParser class (EventDetails) and parse the content of the TicketText field
                Dim EventDetails As New OpsViewEventParser(EventRequest.TicketText)

                ' If there has been a parsing error, the Summary property of TicketDetails will contain "Parse Error",
                ' so we'll throw an exception. The Message property will contain details of the exception encountered
                If EventDetails.Summary = "Parse Error" Then
                    Console.WriteLine("There was a Parsing Error")
                    Throw New Exception(EventDetails.Summary & " - " & EventDetails.Message)
                End If

                'Parsing was successful
                ' Create a new instance of the ServiceNowEvent class and populate its properties from EventDetails
                newServiceNowEvent = New ServiceNowEvent
                With newServiceNowEvent

                    .source = EventDetails.Source
                    .event_class = EventDetails.EventType
                    .node = EventDetails.Host
                    .metric_name = EventDetails.SubSource
                    .type = EventDetails.SubSource
                    .message_key = ""
                    .severity = EventDetails.Priority
                    .description = EventDetails.SmartDescription
                    .additional_info = EventDetails.CreateOpsViewJson
                    .time_of_event = EventDetails.EventTime

                    ' Raise the ServiceNow Event
                    .RaiseServiceNowEvent()

                End With

                If newServiceNowEvent.SNReturnStatus.StartsWith("Error") Then
                    Throw New Exception(newServiceNowEvent.SNReturnMessage)
                End If

                ' No Errors so Update the Ticket_Requests table with the snEventStatus (Completed) and a timestamp
                ' We also save the json we posted to the SN API

                Dim dc As New AutoTicketDBEntities
                Try
                    Dim EventToUpdate = (From i In dc.Ticket_Requests
                                            Where i.ID = EventRequest.ID
                                            Select i).FirstOrDefault()

                    If EventToUpdate IsNot Nothing Then
                        EventToUpdate.snEventRaised = "COMPLETED"
                        EventToUpdate.snEventCreated = Now()
                        EventToUpdate.snEventJSONString = newServiceNowEvent.GeneratedJSONstring.Replace("'", "''")
                        EventToUpdate.snEventSmartTeam = EventDetails.Team.ToUpper
                        EventToUpdate.snEventStatus = "EventCreated"
                        dc.SaveChanges() '####### THIS IS WHERE THE CODE TIMES-OUT ##########
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' Write details of the exception to the Application Log
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("AutoEvent ServiceNow Service", "The ServiceNow Event Service failed. The Exception reported was " & ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
                Finally
                    dc.Dispose()
                End Try


            Catch ex1 As Exception

                Dim dc As New AutoTicketDBEntities

                Try
                    Dim EventToUpdate = dc.Ticket_Requests.SingleOrDefault(Function(i) i.ID = EventRequest.ID)

                    If EventToUpdate IsNot Nothing Then

                        EventToUpdate.snEventRaised = "PROCESSING"
                        EventToUpdate.snEventExceptionText = ex1.Message
                        EventToUpdate.snEventJSONString = newServiceNowEvent.GeneratedJSONstring.Replace("'", "''")
                        EventToUpdate.snEventFailCount += 1
                        de.SaveChanges()

                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' Write details of the exception to the Application Log
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("AutoEvent ServiceNow Service", "The ServiceNow Event Service failed. The Exception reported was " & ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
                Finally
                    dc.Dispose()
                End Try

                EventLog.WriteEvent("AutoEvent ServiceNow Service", "The ServiceNow Auto Event Service encountered an error raising an incident but failed to update the database with details of the error. The Exception whilst attempting to raise the incident was " & ex1.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
            End Try 

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Write details of the exception to the Application Log
        EventLog.WriteEntry("AutoEvent ServiceNow Service", "The ServiceNow Event Service failed. The Exception reported was " & ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error)
    Finally
        de.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub ' END ProcessRequest
```

Comment: Please post the actual exception message.

Comment: The actual exeception returned is {"Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding." & vbCrLf & "The statement has been terminated."} This seems to me to be a red herring as all I'm doing is updating a single record from several hundred that have been successfully read in the first part of the code which uses the same dataEnitity/connections details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by making the first query a list and disposing of the connection then looping though the list. Main change is

```vb
Dim EventQuery As List(Of Ticket_Requests)

    Try

        ' Open a connnection to the database and get any Request that are not COMPLETED

        EventQuery = (From r In de.Ticket_Requests
                      Order By r.Requested
                      Where r.snEventRaised <> "Completed"
                      Select r).ToList()

        Console.WriteLine("We have " & EventQuery.Count & " events to process.")
        ' Iterate through any new records

    Catch ex As Exception

        ' Write details of the exception to the Application Log
        Console.WriteLine("AutoEvent ServiceNow Service - The ServiceNow Event Service failed. The Exception reported was " & ex.Message)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message)
    Finally

        de.Dispose()

    End Try

'Then continue with the Loop code....
```

Hope this helps others.